# install RMySQL on Fedora 21

Tags: mysql, linux, rmysql, fedora-21

I am trying to install RMySQl on Fedora 21, but I get an error:

> ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
>
> Configuration failed because `libmysqlclient` was not found. Try
>   installing:
>
> - deb: `libmysqlclient-dev` | `libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev` (Debian)
> - `libmysqlclient-dev` | `libmariadbclient-dev` (Ubuntu)
> - rpm: `mariadb-devel` | `mysql-devel` (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
> - csw: `mysql56_dev` (Solaris)
> - brew: `mysql-connector-c` (OSX)
>
> If `libmysqlclient` is already installed, check that `'pkg-config'` is
>   in your PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a `libmysqlclient.pc` file.
>
> If `pkg-config` is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR
>   manually via:
>
> `R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'`

Trying to install `mysql-devel` with rpm did not work because of dependencies are not handled by rpm, and by yum also gave errors:

```
Error: Package: mysql-devel-5.5.46-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (/mysql-devel-5.5.46-1.el6.remi.x86_64)
           Requires: real-mysql(x86-64) = 5.5.46-1.el6.remi 
Error: Package: mysql-devel-5.5.46-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (/mysql-devel-5.5.46-1.el6.remi.x86_64)
           Requires: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.46-1.el6.remi
```

I am not sure what to do to make this work

Any help with what steps I need to do would be helpful.

Comment: [These instructions](https://koolinus.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/how-to-install-rmysql-on-centos/) are for CentOS, but they might work on Fedora as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install "mysql-devel" from "remi"  repository, you also need to take "mysql" and "mysql-libs" from the same repository.

And don't try to install "el6" packages (Enterprise Linux 6, aka RHEL or CentOS) on another distro (Fedora).